# Endomorphisms of the maximal ideal of a local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative local  ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$. Is it true in general that $\text{Hom}_R(\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m})\cong \text{Hom}_R(\mathfrak{m}, R)$? What if the Krull dimension of $R$ is equal to one?

Comment: Solved on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/a/178803/23950).

Answer (score -1):

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}_2$, $\mathfrak{m} = 2\mathbb{Z}_2$.  Then $x\mapsto x/2$ is an $R$-module homomorphism $\mathfrak{m}\to R$ whose image isn't contained in $\mathfrak{m}$.

Comment: I'm confused. Is $\mathbb Z_2$ the quotient of $\mathbb Z$ by $(2)$?

Comment: The question here is not about equality, but isomorphism. Also, if $\mathfrak{m}$ is principal (and generated by a nonzerodivisor), then certainly $\text{Hom}_R(\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m}) \cong \text{Hom}_R(\mathfrak{m},R)$

Comment: @MorganO No, is the 2-adic ring.